# Proof check: If $G$ is an infinite group, then it has infinite number of subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, infinite-groups

Prob.48 in Section.6 of "A First Course in Abstract Algebra", Edition 7, Fraleigh.

"Show that a group that has only a finite number of subgroups must be a finite group."

Here is my attempt: $p\rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow \neg q\rightarrow \neg p$

So it is equivalent to prove: "If $G$ is an infinite group, then it has infinite number of subgroups."

Since $G$ is an infinite group, it has infinite elements.

For each $x\in G$, we can construct a cyclic subgroup $\langle x\rangle$. But it is possible that there are redundant cases. For example, for some $x_1\in G, x_2\in G, x_1\neq x_2$, but $\langle x_1 \rangle =\langle x_2 \rangle $.

Define the set:$S=\{\langle x \rangle| \forall x\in G\}$, Now there are two cases:

(1)  If $|S|$ is finite, then there exists some $\langle x\rangle \in S$, such that $|\langle x\rangle|=\infty$. (Otherwise, $G$ will be a finite group, which is a contradiction.) Since $\langle x \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, which contains infinite number of subgroups, $2\mathbb{Z}, 3\mathbb{Z}, ...$, so $\langle x\rangle$ contains infinite number of subgroups. Therefore, $G$ contains infinite number of subgroups.

(2)  If $|S|$ is infinite, then $G$ has infinite cyclic subgroups, hence infinite subgroups. The proof is completed.

Comment: Looks great to me. I like the use of the infinite pigeonhole principle to get a contradiction in the last paragraph.

Comment: It looks correct.

Comment: Thank you, glad you like it! @LeeMosher

Comment: Thank you! @JairTaylor

Comment: It is a bit more efficient to organize the two cases in the reverse order: if there is some element of infinite order then there is a subgroup isomorphic to Z and we are done, and if not, there are infinitely many cyclic subgroups, for the union of the cyclic subgroups is G, so we win again.

Comment: a) $|S|=\infty$ is slightly informal, as the left-hand side usually denotes the cardinality of $S$ and there are are different infinite cardinalities. b) What's your question?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited them, thank you for the suggestions!@MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: Yes, I mean $S$ has finite or infinite elements. I have edited them by using words. Thank you. @joriki